# Complete Workflow task by system using c#

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, tasks, visual-studio-2013

Requirements

I have a custom workflow with three forms

1)Custom association form
2)custom initiation form 
3)Custom Task form

Three user type 
1) Reviewer 
2) Approver 
3) Final Approver

i am getting Approver and Reviewer Value from the custom initiation form.
Reviewer and Approver can be more than one.
now i have created task for all reviewer parallel. Now, if anyone reviewer review the document than other reviewer has not mandatory to do a task. System has to do completed it .

how can i get all the Workflow task for workflow item. ?
Can  any one have a idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like You create only two tasks: one for Approvers and the second for Reviewers. Every task finished when one of persons complete it. If You want to get several reviews, You should create several tasks: for each reviewer individually.

Comment: Hey Alexey , i  have created individual class for all reviewers and aprovers.

Comment: Hey Alexey , i  have created individual class for all reviewers and approvers. but when one reviewer review the document among the 5. than other's review process is not necessary. System has to be completed task of others reviewers who has not perform any action.